Convert SQL database table to a DataFrame with SQLAlchemy’s ORM
In a Flask app, I would like to convert an SQL Lite database table (User here) to a DataFrame.
I have tried this
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(r) for r in User.query.all())

but it returns the error 'User' object is not iterable.
I'm not very familiar with SQLAlchemy. What would be a correct statement?

Try this
from your_flask_app import db
from your_flask_app.models import User
import pandas as pd

users = User.query.all()

user_dicts = [user.__dict__ for user in users]

for user_dict in user_dicts:
    user_dict.pop('_sa_instance_state', None)

df = pd.DataFrame(user_dicts)

print(df.head())


Thanks, it works fine, albeit a bit wordy...

In most cases, it is as simple as
from sqlalchemy import select
df = pd.read_sql_query(select(User), engine)

